# Creating code based on value of macro argument rust

Tags: rust, macros

```
macro_rules! retry_put {
($mod_name:ident, $data_type:ty) => {{
    fn $mod_name() {
      // somelike
       if $mod_name == "red" {
       // generate code written here and not the one in else block
         return u8;
       }
       else {
       // generate code written here and not the one in if
         return "string";
       }
     }
   }
  }
```

I am tring to change the return type based on input basically, if input is true return string else return int.

Or maybe give example for where we are accepting an argument in macro and if its even calculate factorial of 5 and return it as integer and if the argument is odd calculate the factorial of 5 and return it as string. And name of both functions should be same. and logic of calculating 5! should not be repeated.

Comment: How about simply emitting the `if` statement? The compiler will notice that the Boolean expression is constant and only keep the relevant code (provided of course that both branches compile in the given context).

Comment: As return type of both case is different. So, it won't compile

Comment: There is a great difference between checking whether a number is odd (which you can't do without a proc macro) and comparing to a literal (which you can do pretty easily). What is your real case?

Answer (score 1):

You can overload a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! retry_put {
(red, $data_type:ty) => {{
    fn red() {
      return u8;
     }
   }
  }
($mod_name:ident, $data_type:ty) => {{
    fn $mod_name() {
      return "string";
     }
   }
  }
}
```

See [macro_rules!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros.html).

Comment: But there is alot of same logic before returning data, in this case it waill be repeated in both methods (red and $mod_name) also I need name of both methods to be $mod_name

Comment: @KeshavPrince You are also allowed to call macros from other macros.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah that much is clear to me. But give me example where we are accepting a arguement in macro and if its even calulate factorial of 5 and retuen it as integer and if the agruement is odd calculate the factoreial of 5 and retuen it as string. And name of both functions should be same

Comment: @KeshavPrince You are moving the goal posts. The comment I replied to talks about avoiding duplicated code. Now you are asking a question that appears to be completely unrelated to that, and mostly unrelated to your original question. You will have better success if you ask about your actual use case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I am replying for same, if we use macro on duplicate code we won't be able to get the value which that macro calculated, as we need to return that value only

Comment: Could you describe your actual use case in your question? I don't think I can follow the questions in the comments.

Comment: @KeshavPrince I'm confused why "macros can call other macros" doesn't resolve what you're talking about; have a private macro create your 5-factorial with which you can then call `.to_string()` if desired in your user-facing macro.